# Exact sequences of Groupoids?

Tags: category-theory, exact-sequence, groupoids

My question is basically: Is there a good notion of complexes of groupoids and there exactness? I haven't found a definition online.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/crossed+complex

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm a bit confused by this definition. To me, this only seems like the generalization of bounded complexes of abelian groups (since in the notation of nlab, we restrict ourself to $C_k$ abelian for $k\geq 2$).

Comment: It’s the only relevant definition I know. Crossed complexes present strict oo-groupoids in roughly the same way that chain complexes present (certain) spectra. What do you want a notion of complexes of groupoids and exactness for?

Comment: I'm dealing with some fundamental groupoids, and would like to know if things like the long exact sequence of homotopy groups for fibrations translates to groupoids.

Comment: Oh. That’s much easier. It applies with no modifications and all the $\pi_2$ and higher terms just vanish. In particular the homotopy fiber of a map between groupoids, *in oo-groupoids*, is always another groupoid.